# Is the Defect Tied to a User Story

Tags: rally

I am looping through a result set containing defects and I want to check to see if it is tied to a user story.

```
for (i = 0; i < results.defects.length; i++)
{
    defect = results.defects[i];
    var usname = defect.Requirement.Name;

    if (usname.length > 0)
    {
         defectTable.addRow(defect);
    }
}
```

Why does this cause an error? I am new to javascript coding, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code throws errors because *defect.Requirement* might be *null* (if the defect is not associated with a User Story. So, trying to get the *Name* property off a *null* reference would throw an error. I think this code should work for you:

```
for (i = 0; i < results.defects.length; i++)
{
    defect = results.defects[i];

    if (defect.Requirement)
    {
         defectTable.addRow(defect);
    }
}
```

Comment: how simple! i though i was using the attribute incorrectly. thanks so much for your prompt response!!!